# RIP: Hugh Keays-Byrne (Toecutter + Immortan Joe)

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[Hugh Keays-Byrne](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0117412/), who played the role of Toecutter **AND** Immortan Joe from the Mad Max series (36 years apart!) has passed away on the 1st of December, 2020.

[image]

Tributes are flowing in.

https://twitter.com/edgarwright/status/1334200226236788740

https://twitter.com/CharlizeAfrica/status/1334256856198365184

### He will ride eternal, shiny and chrome.

Comment: Don't forget Grunchlk!